# Best resources to learn the Chigorin variation of the Ruy Lopez for both colors?

Tags: opening, books, ruy-lopez

I faced this opening 3 times recently in a tournament, and only scored 1 win and 2 losses. I would like to know: what are the best books or DVDs that cover the Chigorin variation of the Ruy Lopez?

Comment: What's your approximate rating? The book changes depending on how much detail you're willing to go through.

Comment: I'm rated about 2100 FIDE.

Comment: I'm guessing you've been playing as White. Remember that you will probably want to watch Karpov's games in the Ruy Lopez. He was a beast on the white side of it, and it could serve to give you some hints on what is required to play these lines as white.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to say its the best for exhaustiveness but great entertainment [st louis chess club](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NIIy3vZ5Dsc)